# How to add apex error message for an page item in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

In oracle Apex, i can see one error message for an item which is not coming from page validations, i think the error is showing from Apex error, i have attached the screenshot, how to check or remove the error message showing from oracle apex for an item.

Thanks
Abinnaya[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to validations, errors can also be handled with the package `apex_error.add_error`. So the error can be raised from a pl/sql object (function/proc/package/trigger) that is not part of your application definition.

Comment: No its has not been called from any package and from page also in our application

Comment: Without seeing the app i have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

please use this below...
`APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR ( p_message          in varchar2, p_additional_info  in varchar2 default null, p_display_location in varchar2 );`

**Example**

```
APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR (
    p_message   = >'Capitalize must watch',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_with_field_and_notif,
    p_display_location => 'ITEM_LABEL' );
```